# Wordpress: ¿Cómo evitar sobreescribir la base de datos al recargar la página?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Estoy utilizando **$wpdb** para poder escribir una tabla custom de mi base de datos. Pero al recargar la página se insertan los últimos datos insertados.

Tengo el formulario y la conexión de la base de datos en el mismo archivo.

```
<!-- Detalles para guardar datos -->
<?php

// Guardar datos
$cliente = "cliente";
$requerimiento = $_POST['requerimiento'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');
$tabla = 'wp_clientes';

// Conexión de wordpress
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert(
    $tabla,
    array(
        'cliente' => $cliente,
        'requerimiento' => $requerimiento,
        'mensaje' => $mensaje,
        'fecha' => $fecha
    )
);

?>
<!-- Terminan detalles para guardar datos -->

<!-- Formulario para dejar mensajes -->
<div id="formulario-contenedor">

<form id="formulario" action="" method="post">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <select name="requerimiento" id="seleccionar-requerimientos">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea name="mensaje" id="introduce-mensaje" cols="30" rows="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu mensaje"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input id="formulario-enviar-boton" type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </div>

</form>

</div>
<!-- Termina formulario para dejar mensajes -->
```

Comment: Si la inserción se realiza después de enviar un formulario por POST, recargar la página equivale a reenviar el formulario.  Lo que puedes hacer es que después de una inserción exitosa te devuelva a la URL del formulario usando un `header('location ... ')` cosa que al recargar la petición sea de tipo GET

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo en código? No sé donde indicar eso.

Comment: Cual sería la ruta relativa del formulario? algo como `/requerimientos` ?